# SQL Server 2008 R2 warning when tried to execute the script of size approx 500MB

Tags: sql-server, ssms, scripting, downgrade

When I tried executing a SQL script, which was of 500MB approx. Management Studio throws an error

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

My system memory is 8GB and only 3GB is free. I am using a `.bak` file. I even tried `SQLCMD` but it's not working. Any other solution for this?

I faced this issue when I was trying to restore a database using backup of higher version (SQL Server 2014) to a lower version (SQL Server 2008 R2) using scripting method.

The compatibility level of the SQL Server 2014 database is 120.

Comment: Somebody at this link solved this issue by increasing the Max server memory allocated to Sql Server - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307435/getting-error-while-running-50-mb-script-on-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: Please, have a look at this question: [How to move a database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2005](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55055/how-to-move-a-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Have a look at this answer I gave for another question about dealing with large script files - I basically loaded the script into a table and used a cursor to execute the commands - http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/153504/60085